# Creating my own FBX files for XNA? (in 3ds max)

Tags: c#, xna, max, 3ds, fbx

I'm now reading [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) example. I see there is one FBX file and a few texture files in the content project, and that in the code you can choose which "take" to play. In the code it is "Take_001". Please tell me: When I create and animate my own 3D model in 3DS Max, how can I define those takes? plus, are any configurations need to be made when exporting FBX from 3DS Max to XNA?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The model artist does. In his modeling software he can name every bone or animation sequence, and then you can activate it from code.

The built-in FBX pipeline in XNA supports animation only partially, but it doesn't need any pre-configuration. So does the pipeline you linked to.

Comment: Yes, I understand. as you can see in the example I linked to, a custom pipeline is created in order to load the FBX file with the animations. I'm actually asking how to do what you described the artist does. (I have very little experience with Max, and don't really have an artist, so I'm trying to model a few basic examples on my own)

Comment: This isn't a programming-related question, try to ask it in modeling forums.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a stack exchange section related to modeling?

Comment: No, but there's a propose: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications